# Checkbox won't go to the right of asp:Label

Tags: asp.net

I have a div containing an asp:Label and an asp:Checkbox
I am trying to put the label on the left of the checkbox but it just won't go here.
I want both of these on the right side of the page

```
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" style="float:right;" >
        Conclude Case File</asp:Label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="concludeCBox" id="concludeNoteCBox" runat="server"
        style="float:right;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I want both controls to be on the right side of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <asp:Label runat="server" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;" >
        Conclude Case File</asp:Label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="concludeCBox" id="concludeNoteCBox" 
        runat="server" style="float:left;" />
</div>
```

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: aaah, see, I don't know why I didn't think of putting <div style="float:right"> I feel so silly now... Thank you

Comment: This IS cleaner. Didn't think about what we were 'inside of'

Answer (score 1):

asp:Label renders as a SPAN. asp:checkbox renders as an INPUT. Neither SPAN nor INPUT are block elements so float won't apply. My suggestion is to define CSS classes that change them to BLOCK and then position them as you need.

Also keep in mind, when you float:right things appear to render 'backwards.' That is, the FIRST floated-right element will be furthest-right, and so on. So if you wnat the checkbox FIRST, place it first in your markup.